# How to Filter Nested Array Object in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-sdk-js

I am very beginner to AWS DynamoDB, I want to scan the DynamoDB with SENDTO.emailAddress = "first@first.com" as FilterExpression.

The DB Structure looks like this

```
{
    ID
    NAME
    MESSAGE
    SENDTO[
        {
            name
            emailAddress
        }
    ]
}
```

A Sample Data

```
{
    ID: 1,
    NAME: "HELLO",
    MESSAGE: "HELLO WORLD!",
    SENDTO: [
        {
            name: "First",
            emailAddress: "first@first.com"
        },
        {
            name: "Second",
            emailAddress: "second@first.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to retrieve document that match emailAddress. I tried to scan with filter expression and here is my code to retrieve the data. I am using AWS Javascript SDK.

```
let params = {
    TableName : "email",
    FilterExpression: "SENDTO.emailAddress = :emailAddress",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":emailAddress": "first@first.com",
    }
}

let result = await ctx.docClient.scan(params).promise();
```

Comment: You can fetch data from dynamodb table by using the partition key or the combination of partition key and sort key. On the other hand, you can use indexes.

Comment: I tried about partition key and sort key it wasn't helpful, I read that this operation is not supported by DynamoDB. We can query an object attribute but not object array attribute.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 6):

In order to find the item by `sendto` attribute, you need to know both `name` and `emailAddress` attribute value. DynamoDB can't find the data by just one of the attributes in an object (i.e. `email` attribute value alone).

**CONTAINS** function can be used to find the data in List data type.

> CONTAINS is supported for lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a"
>   can be a list; however, "b" cannot be a set, a map, or a list.

**Sample code using Contains:-**

```
var params = {
    TableName: "email",
    FilterExpression: "contains (SENDTO, :sendToVal)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":sendToVal": {
            "name" : "First",
            "emailAddress" : "first@first.com"
        }
    }
};
```

If you don't know the value of `name` and `emailAddress` attribute, you may need to remodel the data to fulfill your use case.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I have remodel the data as two separate arrays.

Comment: If you keep two separate arrays, how would you associate the name and email address?

Comment: This compares the whole object, which can be useful. How do we go about just checking one field of the map?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should create **two tables** for users and for messages.

**The user table** has partition_key: user_id and sort_key: email and a field with an array of his messages ids.

**The message table** has partition_key: message_id and a field with an array of users ids.

When you will get the array of users ids you can use **BATCH GET** query to get all users of one message.

When you will get the array of message ids you can use **BATCH GET** query to get all messages of one user.

If you want to get one user by email you can use **QUERY** method.

[Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchGet-property)

Comment: Thanks, I have remodel the data as two separate arrays. But there is no way in DynamoDB to do the above operation.

Comment: You should use documentClent for this

Comment: I gave you a link

Comment: Yeah I used documentClient and tried your solution, it did work but I want to have the data as a single document.

Comment: Actually this is a feature of nosql databases. Feel free to create separate tables. It will help to manage throwout capacity for each table and save your money.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest Dmitry, FYKI MongoDB supports it though.